# Disabling specific buttons in a row when certain condition is met

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to disable buttons when a certain condition is met. I have 3 rows of buttons and when I click on a button in row A for example, all the other rows of buttons get disabled. I already managed to do that. The only thing I'm still stuck at is, I'm trying to ONLY enable buttons that are next to the clicked button. This is my current code where I'm trying to do that, disabling every button in row A that doesn't meet the condition in the if statement (ch[1] != x && ch[1] != y && ch[1] != ch[1]), sadly this doesn't do anything. All my buttons are named like A1 etc. so the first char is the name of the row and the second char is the button number. Suggestions how I can fix this?

EDIT: I included all of the code to maybe make it easier to understand, but the part of code that I'm talking about is this:

```
  if (ch[0] == 'A')
            {
                Disable_Row(row_B);
                Disable_Row(row_C);

                foreach (Button button in row_A)
                {
                    if (ch[1] != x && ch[1] != y && ch[1] != ch[1])
                    {
                        button.Enabled = false;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        button.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
```

This is all of the code:

---

```
private void Button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button b = (Button)sender;

        var ch = b.Name.ToCharArray();

        int x = ch[1]++;
        int y = --ch[1];

        if(b.BackColor == Color.Green)
        {


            if (ch[0] == 'A')
            {
                Enable_Row(row_B);
                Enable_Row(row_C);
            }

            if (ch[0] == 'B')
            {
                Enable_Row(row_A);
                Enable_Row(row_C);

            }

            if (ch[0] == 'C')
            {
                Enable_Row(row_A);
                Enable_Row(row_B);
            }

            b.BackColor = Color.White;
        }

        else
        {

            if (ch[0] == 'A')
            {
                Disable_Row(row_B);
                Disable_Row(row_C);

                foreach (Button button in row_A)
                {
                    if (ch[1] != x && ch[1] != y && ch[1] != ch[1])
                    {
                        button.Enabled = false;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        button.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (ch[0] == 'B')
            {
                Disable_Row(row_A);
                Disable_Row(row_C);

            }

            if (ch[0] == 'C')
            {
                Disable_Row(row_A);
                Disable_Row(row_B);
            }

            b.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }

    }
```

Comment: My bad, just tried to reduce the code so I only show what I find important, but I'll edit it to contain more.

Comment: So what happens when you debug this step by step?  Place a debug stop on `Button b = (Button)sender;` and step through the code line by line and watch what happens.

Comment: I see that x and y become 52 somehow?

Comment: What were you expecting?  Your x and y are playing with ASCII values.

Comment: Oh I thought it would just increment with 1 or decrement with 1, I saw an example somewhere showing you can increment and decrement chars.